# MyApp-Swift.h file not found. for a specific class only

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I can't import swift header in a specific class in my project, although it worked for all other classes.
I've added

```
#import "MyApp-Swift.h"
```

The interesting thing is that it works if I import it in the implementation file but not in the header file. The error I get is:

```
MyApp-Swift.h file not found.
```

Why?

Comment: so objective-c or swift? it is a huge difference

Comment: If you are referring to the question tags, both are included because the question is about integrating swift code with objective-C.

Comment: Try to name bridging header like this in build settings `MyApp_Swift.h`

Comment: not to tags, to question, we did not know what language is your main for project

Comment: @Lu_ Obviously I'm not trying to import Swift header in a Swift project.. what the point of it? It's not even possible.

Comment: @Evgeny Karkan If you are referring to the "Generated Interface Header Name" property in the build settings, that's already set. If it wasn't set, it would have not worked in all other classes.

Comment: so if you are not trying to import swift header to swift project you are trying to make that in objective-c project? i'm just saying that you can make your question much more readable

Comment: Lu_ I don't understand what you are talking about: "import swift header to swift project". What does that mean? It makes no sense.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've got precedents in the framework for this, but on one ****ing file, it's saying it can't find `MyFramework-Swift.h`. I am using the same import that I found elsewhere in the app for Obj-C headers which use Swift classes.

Answer (score 0):

See section Referencing a Swift Class or Protocol in an Objective-C Header at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html.  It sounds like just a recommendation, but in my experience the compiler actually enforces this.  I've been usually able to work around the problem by using forward declarations, as described in the above-referenced Apple publication, if I really needed to use a Swift class in a header, not source file.

Here is a greatly simplified example.  First some Swift code:

```
import Foundation

// A Swift protocol usable in Objective-C
@objc protocol MySwiftProtocol
{
    func mySwiftProtocolFun();
}

// A Swift class conforming to the Swift protocol
class MySwiftClass : NSObject, MySwiftProtocol
{
    func mySwiftProtocolFun() {
        print("Hello from MySwiftClass!")
    }
}

// Call an Objective-C function
aFunctionOC()
```

Next is an Objective-C header that uses the Swift protocol:

```
#import "Foundation/Foundation.h"

// Forward declaration of a Swift protocol is OK here
@protocol MySwiftProtocol;

@interface MyClassOC : NSObject

// Here we've got a property conforming to the Swift protocol
@property id<MySwiftProtocol> prop1;

-(void)callSwiftProtocol;

@end
```

Implementation of `MyClassOC`:

```
#import "objc.h"

#import "cli_swift-Swift.h"

@implementation MyClassOC

-(void)callSwiftProtocol
{
    [self.prop1 mySwiftProtocolFun];
}

@end
```

Another Objective-C class using `MyClassOC`:

```
#import "objc.h"
#import "cli_swift-Swift.h"

// An Objective-C function that uses an Objective-C class
// that has a property conforming to a Swift protocol
void aFunctionOC()
{
    MyClassOC * x = [[MyClassOC alloc] init];
    x.prop1 = [[MySwiftClass alloc] init];
    [x callSwiftProtocol];
}
```

Finally, here is a bridging header exposing `aFunctionOC()` to Swift:

```
void aFunctionOC();
```

Comment: I see, indeed. My problem arises when I need to make a public property (That should be visible by other classes), that uses a swift protocol. In that case I need to expose the property in the header (and the protocol too). (And I can't forward declare protocols). What do you suggest in this case?

Comment: I don't see a problem forward declaring protocols.  I've added a simple example.  Hopefully it helps.  Please let me know if I misunderstood what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: mhm interesting. If i forward declare the protocol as you did: "@protocol MySwiftProtocol;", I get a warning error: "Cannot find protocol definition for MySwiftProtocol. Don't you get such warning?

Comment: No, not in the above example, but if I define an Objective-C class conforming to the Swift protocol, then I get the warning.  However, I can ignore it, and the Objective-C class is recognized by Swift as conforming to the protocol.  Strange.  Must be one of Swift's growing pains...

Comment: Indeed, this exactly what's happening here. I must ignore the warning, or I have to change code design.